# std::array initializer list initialization in initialization list

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list, initialization-list

Although I much enjoy the new features in C++11, sometimes I feel like I'm missing some of its subtleties.

Initializing the int array works fine, initializing the Element2 vector works fine, but initializing the Element2 array fails.  I think the correct syntax should be the uncommented line, but none of the initialization attempts have succeeded for me.

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

class Element2
{
    public:
            Element2(unsigned int Input) {}
            Element2(Element2 const &Other) {}
};

class Test
{
    public:
            Test(void) :
                    Array{{4, 5, 6}},
                    Array2{4, 5},
                    //Array3{4, 5, 6}
                    Array3{{4, 5, 6}}
                    //Array3{{4}, {5}, {6}}
                    //Array3{{{4}, {5}, {6}}}
                    //Array3{Element2{4}, Element2{5}, Element2{6}}
                    //Array3{{Element2{4}, Element2{5}, Element2{6}}}
                    //Array3{{{Element2{4}}, {Element2{5}}, {Element2{6}}}}
                    {}
    private:
            std::array<int, 3> Array;
            std::vector<Element2> Array2;
            std::array<Element2, 3> Array3;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Test();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this on g++ 4.6.1 and 4.6.2 under MinGW.

How should I correctly go about initializing this array?  Is it possible?

Comment: I guess this doesn't have much to do with initialization lists.  Would it be appropriate to edit the question to make it more to-the-point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to go about this is `Array{{4, 5, 6}}`. You cannot omit braces when you initialize a member with aggregate initialization. The only time you can omit braces is in a declaration of the form

```
T t = { ... }
```

So in your case you have to type out all braces: One for the `std::array` itself, and one for the `int` array. For `Array3`, your syntax is correct too, since `int` can be converted to `Element2` implicitly.

From the remaining commented ones, the `Array3{{{4}, {5}, {6}}}`, `Array3{{Element2{4}, Element2{5}, Element2{6}}}` and `Array3{{{Element2{4}}, {Element2{5}}, {Element2{6}}}}` work too, but are more wordy. However conceptionally the `Array3{{{4}, {5}, {6}}}` one produces the least amount of temporaries on implementations that don't do copy elision (I guess that's irrelevant, but still good to know), even less than the `Array3{{4, 5, 6}}` one, because instead of copy initialization you use copy list initialization for your `Element2`, which doesn't produce an intermediary temporary *by design*.

Comment: Are you saying that it should work fine and GCC is broken? Because the OP is saying that *all* of these variations fail. Also, how does this actually work, since `std::array<Element2>` is not an aggregate? I can cite the spec for requirements on aggregates, and `std::array<Element2>` fails that test. Can you cite the spec on how a non-aggregate can be initialized via aggregate initialization? I'm not saying you're wrong. I freely admit that I've never fully read the C++11 specification. At the same time, I would like some evidence to the veracity of your claim.

Comment: @NicolBolas As I understand it, `std::array<T>` is an aggregate: it is a struct without a user-defined constructor -- and it is explicitly mentioned as an aggregate in the description of `<array>`.

Comment: I read back through the requirements for an aggregate, and conspicuously absent were any requirements that the *members* of the aggregate not have user-provided constructors. So you're right.

Comment: @Ben thanks, not sure why i wrote "emit". Too much Qt programming.

Comment: The code works for me in g++ 4.7, using a snapshot from December.